# Iteration a user-inputted number of times without comparison?

Tags: programming-languages, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to write a program that takes a user input at execution time, labelled n, and then executes a source-code-defined set of instructions n times, one iteration directly after the other, instead of having to increment a counter variable and compare it against the user input after each iteration? In other words, can you just tell the CPU to "do this n times" without the CPU initiating a counter that updates itself and is checked against n after each iteration?

Comment: Is your question about the CPU instruction level (of whatever hardware) or any programming language (however high level)?

Comment: I mean, if you mean the latter, the answer itself may be ambigous as a sufficiently high-level language will just *hide* the fact of counting behind some looping construct. For instance, you could do this in plain bourne shell: `read n; for i in \`seq 1 $n\`; do echo $i; done` -- as you can see, there is no counter, just looping, and still you iterate exactly `n` times -- as was input.

Comment: If you instead wanted to know whether any existing H/W arch has some CPU command which would iterate over a piece of code implicitly, the question gets more interesting. Off the top of my head I recall `LOOPNE` / `LOOPNZ` of x86, but they do decrement the value in a dedicated register which initially contains the number of iterations. If that's OK with you -- the property of the decrement being done *implicitly* is fulfilled, then that's the answer ;-) Otherwise please narrow your question down.

Comment: If you have the instructions as machine code, you could copy them n times into a buffer and mark that buffer as executable. Because you treat this buffer like function, you need a prolog and epilog. Beware that you also need to alter the pc-relative addresses in the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. What you can do is to take the list of instructions to execute, repeating them *n* times (making sure to fix up any absolute jumps), adding [function prologue and epilogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue), saving the result to an [area of memory that is allowed to execute code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) and calling the start of that area as a function.

Note that doing this kind of code generation is really hard to do correctly in languages like C. You would likely either have to go lower, and write your code (or at least some of it) in assembly, or go higher and use a language like C# that allows you to manipulate some code representation, which is then compiled to machine code.

Also, this is fairly unlikely to result in significant performance gains. In fact, it could degrade performance, since your code may no longer fit into the instruction cache of your CPU.

Compilers sometimes partially do this optimization automatically. This is called [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling).